# 20.04 Can't Reach Login Screen when Booting (Blank Screen after Decrypt)--Must Use Recovery Mode

Tags: boot, display, 20.04

I have been trying to get a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 working on my (new) laptop. Things are fine during the first boot, but after that I never seem to make it to the login screen--once I unlock the hard drive (I have encryption set up), everything just kind of stalls and I'm stuck staring at a black screen that stays there until the battery runs out or I force a shutdown.

If I boot into recovery mode and then run apt clean, I can then resume a normal boot from the recovery mode portal and reach the login screen. Once there, I still have issues--e.g. the laptop refuses to go to sleep even when I close it. And then when I shut down or reboot, I have to go through recovery mode once more.

I've tweaked my display and power save settings incessantly and tried a bunch of other fixes, to no avail. I even wiped my hard drive (like a complete nwipe multiple pass ordeal) and reinstalled, but the problem returned immediately.

I'm wondering if there's a driver issue or something similar, but at this point I feel like I'm shooting in the dark. Hopefully someone can help point me in the right direction?

Comment: You may have a BIOS issue. Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the manufacturer's web site and see if there's a newer BIOS.